# Its possible to distinguish between functional and non functional software requirements by computer software?

Tags: requirements, natural-language-processing

I am trying to do a computer program that can distinguish the functional and non-functional requirements written in Arabic languages from the Linguistic structure, so I am I look for the things that distinguish each of them in terms of writing. I wouldn't rely entirely on the structure difference, but it will be supportive of some AI algorithms.

**I know that the difference between functional and non-functional requirements comes down to context and meaning**, but I am looking if there a specific structure for functional requirements that distinguish them from the non-functional requirements. (Perhaps the order of the sentences or the type of sentences, for example, conditional sentences or informational sentences,...)

My question are there clear written rules distinction FR & NFR?

Comment: You've asked this before, and it was closed for being off-topic then... [Structure of functional and non-functional requirements](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/423095/structure-of-functional-and-non-functional-requirements)

Comment: How much accuracy do you require?

Comment: @PhilipKendall yes I asked it before, I think it wasn't clear so I edit it

Comment: @Telastyn Hopefully it's over 50%

Comment: 1) If the requirement contains the word "performance", assign it to the "non-functional" class. 2) Otherwise, assign it to either class at random based on the known percentage of functional vs non-functional requirements. Accuracy > 50% (hopefully)

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am planning to write a heuristic, so I will collect all appropriate rules

Comment: also maybe I will use a table contain all words that usually used in NFR like (speed, security,...) I think it will help me with the rules

Comment: @PhilipKendall Let’s try: “The system shall measure the performance of the runner, such as the timing of one round, the average time per running session...” ;-)

Comment: @Eng.sh Let’s try another one: “The autonomous car should control its speed, in a way to be able to break in time for ensuring the security of pedestrians that are detected on the trajectory by the lidar ”: are two words of your NFR list sufficient to qualify this requirement as non functional ?

Comment: @Chistophe well, the second one is definitely a security requirement .. :-p

Comment: @PhilipKendall: call me nitty, but if you tell askers their questions were off-topic, though they were closed for a very different reason, you may confuse them, and encourage other to vote for closing on-topic questions. Questions about algorithms are **not** off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Non-functional requirements can not reliably be identified based on the vocabulary alone, without a semantic analysis.

Whatever terms or group of terms you may find, I will be able to find a requirement wording that will defeat your automatic categorization. Take the examples in the comments:

- **performance**, which is often associated with NFR: “The system shall measure the performance of the runner, such as the timing of one round, the average time per running session...”. This is a functional requirement of a system that monitors performance.
- **speed** or **security**, also sometimes related to NFR: “The autonomous car should control its speed, in a way to be able to break in time for ensuring the security of pedestrians that are detected on the trajectory by the lidar”. This is a functional requirement since it is not about the speed of the system but a speed that of an object of the system. And the term security is used not as a functional requirement but as a justification for the functional requirement in the statement.

Categorizing requirements is already difficult for humans. For automating it, you’d need a semantic analysis able to determine if the word in your list are used to qualify the system or not. It may also  be easier if you’d narrow down the analysis to sectorial applications, that would allow you to spot absence of functional terms related to the sectorial terminology. But what’s the benefit of identifying  correctly 55% of NFR and having 45% of false positives of missed ones ?

Comment: thank you, using words like(speed, security..) is just an idea it may helps to raise the accuracy of the program. Through experience, I can set a certain percentage for it to affect the final decision. I am thinking to collect more than one technique to get the result, including I can use AI training alg. but I have a small data set so I will not get good accuracy.

Comment: what do you mean by "narrow down the analysis to sectorial applications" I don't get it!

Comment: @Eng.sh I mean reducing the potential domain of the analyses, e.g real estate, autonomous cars, accounting, etc.., so to know a little bit more about the vocabulary that may be used in requirements, especially in functional requirements.

Comment: @Eng.sh if your system is meant as an assistant that proposes some tagging to a human being, and if rates around 50% already facilitate operator’s work, you could indeed try a probabilistic model on words, combination of words and proximity of some words. If you already consider  more advanced techniques, if neural nets are today sufficiently effective for machine translations that is reviewed by humans, it probably can do the trick with a simple tagging exercise, provided that you have a very large annotated corpus for training. May e you could hope 60-70%

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the down voting world !

In theory you could . In practice it is rather rare to have requirements defined well enough so they follow the theory . They are just communication tools between product stakeholders .

F.e. is a requirements uses the word 'in under' it is probably talking about performance. If a requirement uses the word GDPR it is probably about law. But it is rather rare to be so precise.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to do a semiautomated system, now I am looking for some rules that distinguish the FR and NFR to be used alongside AI algorithms

Answer (score -2):

#### We know what we want, but not how to get there.

We have algorithms for this. They are called Data Mining, Evolutionary Algorithms, Genetic Algorithms, and Neural Nets.

Each of these try to guess at an algorithm to predict whether something fits this or that category. Its a guess so it will be wrong. But the more data, and computer cycles thrown into training, the closer the guessed algorithm is to the real algorithm for deciding.

I don't know how much training data you have available. I don't know how difficult the problem itself is. So I don't know how much data and how much training will be needed to get a guess with predictive powers better than random. So I don't know how far applying these techniques will get you.

Comment: Sorry if I ask boring questions, but don’t genetic algorithms expect at least a suitability function to evaluate the gene population and eliminate the less suitable ones ? And is data mining really a family of algorithms rather than an activity/domain of application of algorithms?

Comment: Yes, but you are working on tagged data. the suitability function would simply ask it some number of questions say 100 and give it a ranking of `answered correctly / total answered`. And yes data mining is a generic term for algorithms that break apart big data to find common groups. If one such algorithm reliably groups what you want together its certainly a solution.

Comment: @Kain0_0 Actually I have a labeled data set of 650 requirements only, I don't think its enough

Comment: It might be enough to start. Partition it 80%/20%, us the first 80% to train, use the second 20% to determine how good the resulting algorithm is. You can always increase the sample size over time.